# jsZip : generateAsync is not a function

Tags: javascript, jszip

I have been using jsZip in my AngularJs project. This worked normally before. Recently, I just notice that my Export Zip function doesn't work anymore, and I get an error as the tittle of issue. Could anyone have an idea with that.

Your ideas would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: The error says `obj.generateAsync`, not `zip.generateAsync`. Is `obj` a JSZip instance? And are you using [this library](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)? The methods in the prototype don't look like they belong to that library (at least not the documented one on the aforementioned web page), perhaps you're using an older version of it?

Comment: I am using jszip 3.1.3 which is the latest. I also remove and install it back via bower. My obj here is JSZip instance. I also think the generate() function is for version 2.x.x , but  I don't know why. right now I can use generate() instead of generateAsync(). 

Before it worked perfectly with generateAsync(), yet now not anymore.

Comment: You're sure you're not loading two different versions of JSZip in your page?

Comment: pretty sure. I have only one. I also think as you at first .

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/887dcd8af9f321edc8b3e693da09502e5d3bc89d/documentation/upgrade_guide.md#from-2x-to-300), you'll notice that various methods that are present on your object (like `crc32` and `utf8*`) were removed in JSZip 3.x, so I can only conclude that you're using an outdated version.

Comment: thanks for that. I already removed and reinstall the latest version. and it generateAsync() worked on my code before. sorry for keeping saying the same thing since I don't really understand why. I know my attached screenshot is an old version, but I did add the latest version in code.

It makes no sense.

Comment: I found that another library included on my page, specifically XLSX (xlsx.full.min.js), loads JSZip internally (an older version). which overrides the version of JSZip that I included.